# C++ matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: c++, matrix, directx, linear-algebra

When working with 3d graphics, sample shaders *USUALLY* use the following operation for vector position transformation:

```
result = mul(matrix, vector);
```

This obviously means the same as:

```
result = mul(vector, matrix_transposed);
```

*Also, just to mention, most linear algebra libraries prefer to only leave the `vector * matrix` multiplication operation for simplicity.*

---

***Now:*** let's say I want to transform some `vector` *(position, for example)*, using some concrete matrix *(to be concrete, let's use `D3DX` matrix operations)*. So, I construct simple *world-view-projection* matrix and then pass it to my shader.

```
  D3DXMatrixRotationX(&world, 0.05f);

  D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&view, &D3DXVECTOR3(400.0f, 80.0f, 0.0f),
                            &D3DXVECTOR3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.0f),
                            &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

  D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&projection, 0.5f, 800.0f / 600.0f, 1.0f, 1500.0f);

  D3DXMATRIX wvp = world * view * projection;

  Set Shader Parameter (wvp); // Pseudocode here
```

### Question:

---

*And here comes the part I can't understand - if done this way, the shader code should be*

```
result = mul(vector, wvp)
```

*for this transformation to work(vector is multiplied from the left side of the matrix).*

Why does this happen? How do most *sample shaders* have the `result = mul(wvp, vector)` transformation inside them (and they *don't transpose* the matrix before setting it as a parameter)?

**Where am I wrong?**

*Thank you.*

---

A bit more information - `D3DX` matrix has *row-major* alignment and I am using the corresponding function, which takes a *row-major* matrix as a parameter (`cgSetMatrixParameterfr` in my particular case).

*Of course, I could "transpose" that matrix by calling the function `cgSetMatrixParameterfc`, which treats input data as column-major matrix (and "automatically" **transposes** it), but that would be ridiculous.*

Comment: AFAIK the equality `v*A=A^T*v` does not hold for matrix multiplication. However, `(v*A)^T=A^T*v^T` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention in mathematics (and thus in programming) is that you multiply the vector by a linear transformation from the right: `matrix * vector == transformed vector`. So I don't understand you complain. The matrix is already set to the right one. If you want to multiply the vector from the left **then** you need to transpose the matrix: `result = mul(vector, transpose(wvp))`

**EDIT:** OK, Direct3D actually does the opposite. It multiplies vectors from the left (treats them as rows rather than columns). OpenGL, for example, multiplies from the right as normal people do. So you need to load the transposed matrix to the cg program.

Comment: Could you explain then why does the code (DX-specific) generates the matrix, which is `transposed` comparing to multiplication convention? *You could test it yourself, for this code to work shader has to have a `mul(vector, matrix)` instruction, but not the `mul(matrix, vector)`.*

Comment: Note: The cue was that you wrote `world * view * projection`. The order here may be right iff you project as `vector * world * view * projection`.

Answer (score 0):

If both matrices are diagonal, square and have same size, then the multiplication is commutative.